# Solve equation using 'in' operator

Tags: python, for-loop

I have to solve P = A + BX + CX^2 + DX^3, but **not** doing this:

```
a = float(input(" give a "))
b = float(input(" give b "))
c = float(input(" give c "))
d = float(input(" give d "))
x = float(input(" give x "))
p = a + b*x + c*x*x + d*x*x*x
print(" p = ", p)
```

I have to use:

```
for i in (a, b, c, d):
    . . .
```

What should I do?

Comment: I'm not being rude, merely telling you what's expected on this website.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of your constants, i.e. `a,b,c,d` and then iterate through the loop and solve the equation. See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp) to get started with `for` loops.

Also, you can see a pattern that like this:
`a*x^i + b*x^(i+1) + c*x^(i+2) + d*x^(i+3)`, use this pattern to calculate corresponding term for each iteration and sum over them to get your desired answer.

Comment: Exponentiation in Python uses `**` not `^` as some some other languages do. I also think using `i` in the second paragraph is confusing given that the OP said they were required to use `for i in (a, b, c, d):` which is clearly a different `i`.

Comment: I am just explaining to OP that how pattern is repeating so that OP can get insight of using for loop here.

Comment: I noticed that, which is why I didn't downvote your answer despite thinking it might be confusing and could be improved.